# phpMyAdmin - Could not load import plugins

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I go to "Import" section of phpMyAdmin (server_import.php) I get below error:

```
Could not load import plugins, please check your installation!
```

I am not able to see the page or the "Browse" button etc.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the current stable version (4.0.9), import plugins are located in the phpMyAdmin folder, under libraries/plugins/import. They are probably missing from your installation.

Comment: It is a fresh install. I checked the directory you mentioned, and it is available.

Comment: Please describe your web server's platform: OS, web server (Apache?). Also, are there errors in your web server's log?